# How to print user role in body profile page

Tags: theming, hooks

I've got two roles in my website and I'd like to print the role name in the user profile page body classes for the user being viewed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **html.tpl.php** template uses the `$classes` variable to add classes to the body element. You can use [`template_preprocess_html()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7) to add classes to this variable. Add this function to your theme's **template.php**

```
//Replace MYTHEME with the name of your theme
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

  //Check if the path is a profile page with a valid user
  if(preg_match('/^user\/(\d+)/', current_path(), $matches) == 1) {
    if($user = user_load($matches[1])) {

      //Add each role to the $classes_array which makes it available in $classes
      foreach($user->roles as $rid => $role) {
        $variables['classes_array'][] = str_replace(' ', '-', $role);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Shawn thanks for your help. Maybe I've to edit the question. What I meant is: not to get the current logged in user role, but to get the role of the profile page user I'm visiting. I.e. if I see a user profile page with `role-A` I would like to have in the body classes `user-role-a`, and so on.

Comment: I'm trying with this code in the `preprocess_html` function but without success: `if (arg(0) == 'user' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
    $user = user_load((int) arg(1));

    if (in_array('role-a', $user->roles)) {
      $vars['classes_array'][] = 'user-role-a';
    }

    if (in_array('role-b', $user->roles)) {
      $vars['classes_array'][] = 'user-role-b';
    }
  }
`

Comment: All that's need is a simple mod that makes `$user` refer to the currently viewed user. See above.

Comment: Sorry for my inexperience. Works perfectly... Thank you!